# This branch cannot be rebased due to too many changes

Tags: git, github, gerrit

I am migrating my Gerrit repository into GitHub. The repository has around 10,000 commits and I want to migrate the commit history too into GitHub. To make this work I have carried out the following steps:-

1. Changed the remote URL of the Gerrit repo to point at the empty GitHub repo -
   `git remote set-url origin https://github.com/myorg/myproject.git`
2. Created a replica of the `master` branch locally - `git checkout -b MasterReplica`
3. Merged `origin/main` branch into `MasterReplica` branch allowing unrelated histories - `git merge --allow-unrelated-histories -m "Merging branches from 2 repos" origin/main`
4. Pushed `MasterReplica` to origin - `git push -u origin MasterReplica`
5. Raised pull request on `origin/MasterReplica` to be merged into `origin/main`
6. Clicked on `Rebase and Merge` which throws error -> **"This branch cannot be rebased due to too many changes"**

Looks like GitHub cannot merge a PR with too many commits hence the error. Is there any workaround to get this done? Thanks.

Comment: Rebase locally? (and then push to master.) Why do you need GitHub to do this?

Comment: The `main` branch is protected, all the code that goes into `main` is supposed to go via PR, but yes this case is different so what you're saying makes sense. Thanks!