# What constitutes a "branch with too many changes" for Github PR rebase merging?

Tags: github, rebase, pull-request

What criteria does Github use to determine whether or not a given PR "has too many changes" for rebase-merging?

I've worked on a refactoring effort recently and after submitting and getting approval in the PR, I got the following message from Github's UI, preventing me from rebase-merging the change:

> This branch cannot be rebased due to too many changes

[image]

At the time, I had no idea what exactly the limit was, so I split my ~30-commit PR into 2 ~15-commit changes, which made the restriction go away.

I found a question around the same limitation, but it doesn't focus on what these limits are, asking for workarounds instead:

- [This branch cannot be rebased due to too many changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73693369/this-branch-cannot-be-rebased-due-to-too-many-changes)

I'm now doing another change which also has a similar number of commits and wanted to know exactly what rules Github uses to determine whether or not a given PR "has too many changes" so that I can split my PRs accordingly upfront and avoid rework both on my end as well as on reviewer's.

I tried finding official documentation on this to no avail. Unfortunately, the only way I'm aware of to test it is to submit the PR and check if the message comes up. This however becomes unfeasible since *the message only shows after all checks have succeeded*, meaning I have to *also* get actual reviews on the change to check whether they are mergeable or not. If I then find out it is not mergeable, I have to create a separate PR and split the change, wasting everybody's time on re-reviews.

Many different aspects (or a combination of multiple aspects) could be the cause for this:

- Number of commits
- Number of affected files
- Number of affected lines
- Number of conflicts with base branch
- etc

I've been using GH for a long time and had never seen this message until a couple weeks ago, so *I assume* it is either some new feature, or maybe a restriction depending on the type of plan used by my company.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is almost certainly a timeout-based situation.  GitHub uses libgit2 to perform rebases and how long a rebase takes depends on the number of commits, the complexity of the changes in each of those commits, and the complexity related to the repository (size of objects that must be looked up, etc.).  libgit2 doesn't have all the optimizations of regular Git, but regular Git cannot rebase in a bare repository, so the use of libgit2 is required.

So there's no fixed limit in the number of commits or the complexity, only that if it takes longer than whatever the timeout is, the operation will fail, and you'll be left with that message.  One way to avoid this is to use regular merge commits, which while not immune from timing out, are less likely to do so because the merge involves only three commits, not however many are in your branch.

Comment: Do you have any reference for the information you are providing? As for the merge commit, I'm aware that performing a merge-commit doesn't have this problem but I wanted to have a linear history in these particular cases so I was purposefully avoiding that merge option.

Comment: I don't.  I'm one of the folks on call for the underlying internal APIs, but I don't control that message or the web interface.  I can't say 100% for certain that it's timeout-based, but I can't think of any other reason this message would occur.  If you want more certainty, you'll have to ask GitHub Support.  I _am_ certain how GitHub does rebases, though.

Comment: @bk2204 if it's of interest to you, this happened again to two of my PRs ~3 days ago; the bigger one I fixed trough "dummy commit - push - removal of dummy commit - force-push," and the other one solved itself when there actually was a conflict with upstream. So, really confused why non-conflicting new commits don't re-trigger evaluation of "conflictiveness"… These branches were fast-forward, 4 and 1 commit only.